# Is it possible to create task with logon type TASK_LOGON_S4U without elevated privileges?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-task-scheduler

I need to create a C++ application which schedules a task using Windows Task Scheduler. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/time-trigger-example--c---) example can be used as a code to reproduce my problem.

When this code is used without changes (with `TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN` logon type), it runs well with current user privileges, but when logon type is swapped with `TASK_LOGON_S4U` (both for principal and `RegisterTaskDefinition` method), program fails with the following output:

```
Error saving the Task : 80070005
```

This code is `E_ACCESS_DENIED`. Running the example with elevated privileges ("as Administrator") has no errors for both logon types.

I haven't found any information in Microsoft documentation about privileges needed to create tasks with different logon types. So is creating such a task impossible without elevated privileges, or am I missing something?

Comment: Seems logical to me since a S4U task will run as local system (which is a local administrator) and then impersonate/identify as the user, but in the same process. Or also make sure the user in question can logon as a batch https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/760ee186-8074-40a5-95b0-35d17c2bdfab/log-on-as-batch-job-right

Comment: There is a similar discussion [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ad5f4e9-58b5-4f92-9858-965a9a8597bd/s4u-logon-type-with-different-account-access-denied), because of the S4U account permission requirements, your idea cannot be realized